# Order By a Varchar column containing numbers with a dash (1060006-19)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT varcharColumn 
FROM tableA
ORDER BY varcharColumn ASC
```

Gives me

```
1060006-1
1060006-10  
1060006-11  
1060006-12  
1060006-13  
1060006-15
1060006-16  
1060006-17  
1060006-18  
1060006-19
1060006-20
1060006-2
```

etc

What I want is

```
1060006-1
1060006-2
1060006-3
```

etc

Can Order By achieve this? Or do I need something more fancy?

Using this gave me the results in the picture below:

```
ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN varcharcolumn like '%-%' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END,
LEN(varcharcolumn)
```

[image]

Comment: That you are interested in the two separate strings (you want to treat the string '1060006-2' as if it where two numbers 1060006 and 2 or two strings '1060006' and '02') indicates that this should better be two separate columns. You may want to change this in your table design and queries like the one needed here would become extremely simple.

Comment: I agree, as the number after the dash is essential a version number. But too many things rely on how it's currently set up and I don't think I'll be given time to change it.

Comment: A common situation. Unfortunately it's usually even *more* things that rely on it in the future, so it gets worse and worse. An option might be to introduce the separate columns and make the composed number a computed column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the efficient way would be using splitted columns in `Order By`

**Schema:**

```
CREATE TABLE #TAB (VARCHARCOLUMN VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO #TAB 
SELECT '1060006-1' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT  '1060006-10' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT  '1060006-11' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT  '1060006-12' 
UNION ALL  
SELECT '1060006-13' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT  '1060006-15' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT  '1060006-16' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT  '1060006-17' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT '1060006-18' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT  '1060006-19' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT  '1060006-20' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT  '1060006-2'
```

Now split the varchar column in parts by `-` and get the order

```
SELECT VARCHARCOLUMN
,CAST(SUBSTRING(VARCHARCOLUMN,1,CHARINDEX('-', VARCHARCOLUMN)-1) AS BIGINT) AS PART1
,CAST(SUBSTRING(VARCHARCOLUMN,CHARINDEX('-', VARCHARCOLUMN)+1,LEN(VARCHARCOLUMN)) AS INT) AS PART2
FROM #TAB
ORDER BY PART1, PART2
```

This will return

```
+---------------+---------+-------+
| VARCHARCOLUMN |  PART1  | PART2 |
+---------------+---------+-------+
| 1060006-1     | 1060006 |     1 |
| 1060006-2     | 1060006 |     2 |
| 1060006-10    | 1060006 |    10 |
| 1060006-11    | 1060006 |    11 |
| 1060006-12    | 1060006 |    12 |
| 1060006-13    | 1060006 |    13 |
| 1060006-15    | 1060006 |    15 |
| 1060006-16    | 1060006 |    16 |
| 1060006-17    | 1060006 |    17 |
| 1060006-18    | 1060006 |    18 |
| 1060006-19    | 1060006 |    19 |
| 1060006-20    | 1060006 |    20 |
+---------------+---------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN varcharcolumn like '%-%' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END,
LEN(varcharcolumn), varcharcolumn
```

This way you'd get those with dashes at the top first; then the `LEN(XX)` part is so that 1-10 does not appear right after 1-1 without any need to convert to decimal. You're free to remove the ordering by length anyway

If you want only thsoe with dashes to appear, then maybe you should do a where clause too.

Comment: I got your expected output to appear. If you want only those with '-' to appear, what you need is a WHERE clause @JackReilly

Comment: I think the difference is because you're ordering by the length and when they have the same length letting the system decide. I suggest adding `, varcharcolumn` to the `order by` clause.

Comment: It's really hard to assume what he wants next as per his given expected output. So I just thought to leave it to him the next order by-s necessary. Anyway, approved your edit. Thanks! @SteveLovell

Answer (score 0):

Bennioe put me on the correct path. In the end this got me the output I wanted.

```
SELECT varcharcolumn 
FROM TableA
order by LEN(varcharcolumn ) asc, varcharcolumn asc
```

[image]

Comment: ... which only works as long as all strings start with the same number (e.g. 1060006) of course.

Comment: Have you tested with this data: '1060006-1', '1060005-1', '1060006-10', '1060005-10'?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner The number after the dash is a version number so wouldn't it still be correct? 1060006-1, 1060006-2, 1060007-1, 1060007-2?

Comment: @Jack Reilly: No. What you show could be sorted with `order by varcharcolumn` alone. Try Trung Duong's example instead.